# XPath descendant-or-self vs ancestor-or-self in predicate?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XPath expression that is working the way I want it to work but I don't understand ***why*** it's working.  Here is the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PurchaseOrders>
  <PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
    <Address Type="Shipping">
      <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
      <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
      <City>Mill Valley</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <Zip>10999</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
    <Address Type="Billing">
      <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
      <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
      <City>Old Town</City>
      <State>PA</State>
      <Zip>95819</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
    <DeliveryNotes>Please leave packages in shed by driveway.</DeliveryNotes>
    <Items>
      <Item PartNumber="872-AA">
        <ProductName>Lawnmower</ProductName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
        <Comment>Confirm this is electric</Comment>
      </Item>
      <Item PartNumber="926-AA">
        <ProductName>Baby Monitor</ProductName>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
        <ShipDate>1999-05-21</ShipDate>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </PurchaseOrder>
  <PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99505" OrderDate="1999-10-22">
    <Address Type="Shipping">
      <Name>Cristian Osorio</Name>
      <Street>456 Main Street</Street>
      <City>Buffalo</City>
      <State>NY</State>
      <Zip>98112</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
    <Address Type="Billing">
      <Name>Cristian Osorio</Name>
      <Street>456 Main Street</Street>
      <City>Buffalo</City>
      <State>NY</State>
      <Zip>98112</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
    <DeliveryNotes>Please notify me before shipping.</DeliveryNotes>
    <Items>
      <Item PartNumber="456-NM">
        <ProductName>Power Supply</ProductName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <USPrice>45.99</USPrice>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </PurchaseOrder>
  <PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99504" OrderDate="1999-10-22">
    <Address Type="Shipping">
      <Name>Jessica Arnold</Name>
      <Street>4055 Madison Ave</Street>
      <City>Seattle</City>
      <State>WA</State>
      <Zip>98112</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
    <Address Type="Billing">
      <Name>Jessica Arnold</Name>
      <Street>4055 Madison Ave</Street>
      <City>Buffalo</City>
      <State>NY</State>
      <Zip>98112</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
    <Items>
      <Item PartNumber="898-AZ">
        <ProductName>Computer Keyboard</ProductName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <USPrice>29.99</USPrice>
      </Item>
      <Item PartNumber="898-AM">
        <ProductName>Wireless Mouse</ProductName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <USPrice>14.99</USPrice>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </PurchaseOrder>
<PurchaseOrder1 PurchaseOrderNumber="99504" OrderDate="1999-10-22">
    <Address Type="Shipping">
      <Name>Jessica Arnold</Name>
      <Street>4055 Madison Ave</Street>
      <City>Seattle</City>
      <State>WA</State>
      <Zip>98112</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
    <Address Type="Billing">
      <Name>Jessica Arnold</Name>
      <Street>4055 Madison Ave</Street>
      <City>Buffalo</City>
      <State>NY</State>
      <Zip>98112</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
    <Items>
      <Item PartNumber="898-AZ">
        <ProductName>Computer Keyboard</ProductName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <USPrice>29.99</USPrice>
      </Item>
      <Item PartNumber="898-AM">
        <ProductName>Wireless Mouse</ProductName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <USPrice>14.99</USPrice>
      </Item>
    </Items>
<PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99504" OrderDate="1999-10-22">
    <Address Type="Shipping">
      <Name>Jessica Arnold</Name>
      <Street>4055 Madison Ave</Street>
      <City>Seattle</City>
      <State>WA</State>
      <Zip>98112</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
    <Address Type="Billing">
      <Name>Jessica Arnold</Name>
      <Street>4055 Madison Ave</Street>
      <City>Buffalo</City>
      <State>NY</State>
      <Zip>98112</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
    <Items>
      <Item PartNumber="898-AZ">
        <ProductName>Computer Keyboard</ProductName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <USPrice>29.99</USPrice>
      </Item>
      <Item PartNumber="898-AM">
        <ProductName>Wireless Mouse</ProductName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <USPrice>14.99</USPrice>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </PurchaseOrder>
  </PurchaseOrder1>

</PurchaseOrders>
```

This is my XPath expression:

```
/PurchaseOrders/descendant-or-self::*[@OrderDate="1999-10-22" and 
                                      not(ancestor-or-self::PurchaseOrder1)]
```

This gives me all purchase orders with an order date of 10/20/1999 except the one under `PurchaseOrder1` which is exactly the result I want.  But what confuses me is that I had to use `ancestor-or-self` instead of `not(descendant-or-self::PurchaseOrder1)` to get the results that I want. Wondering why that is since the `PurchaseOrder` that I want to exclude is a descendant of `PurchaseOrder1` and not an ancestor? If I use `descendant-or-self` it actually includes the one under `PurchaseOrder1`.

Also, if anyone has suggestions on how to get the same results with a different expression, I'd appreciate that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `ancestor-or-self::PurchaseOrder1` works because it's within a predicate whose context nodes are going to be `PurchaseOrder` elements (with the specified `@OrderDate`).  There are no `PurchaseOrder` elements at all that have `PurchaseOrder1` *descendants* (only *ancestors*), so it's only the `ancestor::` axis that can make the differentiation you seek.

If your actual XML is no more complicated than the shown XML, you can avoid the `ancestor::` and `descendant::` axes altogether with this simpler XPath,

```
/PurchaseOrders/PurchaseOrder[@OrderDate="1999-10-22"]
```

because all `PurchaseOrder` elements of interest are children of `PurchaseOrders`.

If there are elided levels of heritage above `PurchaseOrder` necessitating the  `ancestor::` or `descendant::` axes, consider this simpler XPath:

```
//PurchaseOrder[@OrderDate="1999-10-22"][not(ancestor::PurchaseOrder1)]
```

Comment: Thank you @kjhughes.  The real xml is much more complicated so I can't use the 1st simpler path.  I'll play with the 2nd variation to see if I can work with that.  The real xml is actually checking for an attribute that could be at multiple levels in the xml and I want to exclude just certain nodes and their descendants containing that same attribute.  So I might need what I have.  But this gives me the explanation I was looking for and some other things to test.  Thank you!